# как изменить язык в SQL SHELL (psql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, psql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скриншоте у меня похоже установлен п умолчанию русский язык и это вызывает некоторые проблемы с отображением т.к. sql shell (psql) 8-битный. Как поменять язык на английский?

команда 0

эта команда  не помогает

**SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и эта тоже

**lc_messages = 'C'**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191428/change-language-of-system-and-error-messages-in-postgresql, Чтобы долго не искал `lc_messages = 'C'` так попробуй

Comment: возможно я делаю что-то не так, но похоже это не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В командной строке перед запуском psql набери chcp 1251, а ещё лучше используй в качестве LC_COLLATE значение ru_RU.UTF-8, а в командной строке - chcp 65001.

Comment: спасибо, команда \! chcp 1251 сработала

Comment: @ПавелСоляник, Если ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как решение поставив галку на нем

Answer (score 0):

Перерыл весь инет, нашёл :)

```
1. Win + R -> пишем regedit

2. Находим папку Компьютер\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor

3. Правая кнопка мыши -> создать раздел, называем Autorun, жмём Enter

4. Тыкаем правой кнопкой мыши на Autorun -> изменить

5. Устанавливаем значение chcp 1251 -> ОК
```

После повторного запуска всё работает, кодировка не слетает :)